# Rails - using namespace controllers to organize files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces

I am trying to learn about namespacing.

I've asked a few questions on this topic previously, but I'm not understanding what is going on.

I have made a folder in my controller's folder called 'features'. In it, I have saved a file called app_roles_controller.rb.

The first line of that controller is:

```
class Features::AppRolesController < ApplicationController
```

The purpose of the features folder is so I can organise my files better (that's it).

In my routes.rb, I have tried:

```
resources :app_roles, :namespace => "features", :controller => "app_roles"
```

I have also tried:

```
namespace :features do
  resources :app_roles 
end
```

I have a model (top level) called app_role.rb and I have a views folder saved as views/features/app_roles which then has the index, show etc files in it.  The table in my schema is called 'app_roles".

When I rake routes for app_roles, I get:

```
Paths Containing (app_role):
app_roles_path  GET /app_roles(.:format)    
app_roles#index {:namespace=>"features"}

POST    /app_roles(.:format)    
app_roles#create {:namespace=>"features"}

new_app_role_path   GET /app_roles/new(.:format)    
app_roles#new {:namespace=>"features"}

edit_app_role_path  GET /app_roles/:id/edit(.:format)   
app_roles#edit {:namespace=>"features"}

app_role_path   GET /app_roles/:id(.:format)    
app_roles#show {:namespace=>"features"}

PATCH   /app_roles/:id(.:format)    
app_roles#update {:namespace=>"features"}

PUT /app_roles/:id(.:format)    
app_roles#update {:namespace=>"features"}

DELETE  /app_roles/:id(.:format)    
app_roles#destroy {:namespace=>"features"}
```

I can't understand what it is that I'm doing wrong.

When I try:

```
http://localhost:3000/app_roles#index
```

I get an error that says:

```
uninitialized constant AppRolesController
```

When I try:

```
http://localhost:3000/features/app_roles#index
```

I get an error that says:

```
No route matches [GET] "/features/app_roles"
```

I'm looking for a plain English explanation of how to set this up. I've tried the programming ruby book (several times over).

Please, can you help me understand what needs to happen to introduce organisational files in my rails app?

Comment: Seriously your are triggering this url? `

http://localhost:3000/features/app_roles#index`? Remove the `#index` in your url.

Comment: @araratan - that doesnt work either. When I try:  http://localhost:3000/features/app_roles, I get an error that says: No route matches [GET] "/features/app_roles"

Comment: Have you had a read through the rails guide on routing? It's often a good place to look. The section on namespacing is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing it suggests that you try something like: `resources :app_roles, module: 'features'` which would lead to a route like `features_app_roles_path` for the index page (but I recommend reading that guide to understand more about how it works and what to expect it to do)

Comment: Yes - I've read it. I can't find anything that is written without jargon. I am so confused by these resources. Thanks anyway - I'll keep trying. It might be too far out of my grasp to understand this. Maybe keeping everything disorganised at the top level is easier that figuring out how to translate coding guides to english.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your other attempt was actually correct. [As outlined in the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), if you want to generate routes for the resource `app_roles` under the namespace `features` you can add the following to your `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :features do
  resources :app_roles
end
```

Now, you run `rake routes` you will see the following:

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
    features_app_roles GET    /features/app_roles(.:format)          features/app_roles#index
                       POST   /features/app_roles(.:format)          features/app_roles#create
 new_features_app_role GET    /features/app_roles/new(.:format)      features/app_roles#new
edit_features_app_role GET    /features/app_roles/:id/edit(.:format) features/app_roles#edit
     features_app_role GET    /features/app_roles/:id(.:format)      features/app_roles#show
                       PATCH  /features/app_roles/:id(.:format)      features/app_roles#update
                       PUT    /features/app_roles/:id(.:format)      features/app_roles#update
                       DELETE /features/app_roles/:id(.:format)      features/app_roles#destroy
```

The first line for example means that if you make a GET request to `/features/app_roles` it will be routed to the `index` action in the `features/app_roles` controller.

In other words, if you visit http://localhost:3000/features/app_roles it will route the request to `index` action that is located in `app/controllers/features/app_roles_controller.rb` which it expects to have the class `Features::AppRolesController`.

So your `app/controllers/features/app_roles_controller.rb` file should look something like this:

```
class Features::AppRolesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: Does that mean I also make a model folder called "Features" and keep app_role.rb in that folder? If so, do I need to do something to communicate that the name of the table in the schema is "app_roles" instead of something that includes a reference to "feature".